# (homomorphism) If the differential equation solutions are equal at the origin they are equal?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Proof:
[image]

I get everything it says but literally the last line. Why can can we conclude that they are equal just because they are equal at the origin?

For reference I will include something that might be related by I don’t know how exactly.

[image]

Comment: two solutions differ by a constant, which is $0$ if they are the same somewhere

Comment: How do we know they differ by a constant only (in that case, I get it)? Why can’t they have different functions that satisfy the equation but they happen to intersect at the origin

Comment: What's the title of the book ?

Comment: Artin Abstract Algebra, but Ifigured it out thanks to the hints on this site

Comment: Thanks Dhdh I didn't know he wrote that book. Only knows his book Algebra.